# How to prevent Thunderbird from updating automatically?

Tags: upgrade, updates, thunderbird, synaptic, lightning

today at startup my Tb (not precisely sure what version it was) asked if it should check compatibility of the lightning calendar addon. That is to say it displayed in a list windows the only item: lightning and said it was not compatible. Choices were "check" or "don't" check compatibility. I clicked on check and after nothing happened for several minutes on "cancel". So, now my Tb is upgraded to 15.0 and Lightning isn't there anymore. It never asked me to upgrade anyway and I urgently need my calendar now.

Any suggestions warmly welcome!

Holger

**Edit**: Solved!I had to reinstall lightning and provider for google calendar addons - although they were already installed and obviously falsely not found compatible.

The question now is how to avoid automatic updates in tb in general...

Comment: Solved!I had to reinstall lightning and provider for google calendar addons - although they were already installed and obviously falsely not found compatible. Question now being how to avoid automatic updates in tb in general...

Comment: All software is updated centrally via the Update Manager in Ubuntu. As already stated, you can use Synaptic to lock the version, but i wouldn't do that (let yourself have the latest and greatest version if you can!). Instead, hit "Don't Check" when that window pops up again, and make the decision on compatibility yourself. If something plays up, disable it, if not, you can make the choice to leave well alone.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to your second question:

**Avoiding automatic updates for a specific package**

Install synaptic package manager if you haven't done so already

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open it up and search for the package in question, e.g. `thunderbird`. Mark the package you want to modify and head to `Package` --> `Lock version`.

Do the same for all `thunderbird` related packages and `thunderbird` will not get upgraded until you remove the version lock flag.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem described in [#108206](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1082062) I'm using the following pinning file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-lock-thunderbird`

```
# thunderbird and lightning (and companions) need to be locked !

Package: thunderbird
Pin: version 16.*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: xul-ext-lightning
Pin: version 1.8*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: xul-ext-calendar-timezones
Pin: version 1.8*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: xul-ext-gdata-provider
Pin: version 1.8*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

See also [#1082089](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightning-extension/+bug/1082089) for the additional pins.