# Stop Ubuntu from upgrading with specific updates

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent Thunderbird from updating automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190467/how-to-prevent-thunderbird-from-updating-automatically)

I have PPA installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 system and it keeps prompting me with an update for a certain application; this update breaks the software. The PPA itself also has many different applications which work great. Is there anyway to keep this ppa installed, with it updating the other applications, while stopping it from updating one of them.

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190467/how-to-prevent-thunderbird-from-updating-automatically/190482#190482 (explanation for thunderbird but applies to all packages)